# Cakephp Multiple Checkboxes in a row

Tags: css, cakephp, checkbox, formhelper

When the form helper creates checkboxes, they stack vertically.  I want them in a row horizontally to save space.  How do I do this?

Comment: can you post the HTML that is being generated? Also look at the CSS for the checkboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing each checkbox individually.

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->checkbox('somegroup', array('value' => 'foo', 'style' => 'float: left; display: inline')); 

echo $this->Form->checkbox('somegroup', array('value' => 'bar', 'style' => 'float: left; display: inline')); 
?>
```

Comment: No luck.  Comes out vertically stacked, even on a blank page.

Comment: You should use CSS classes anyway,

Comment: revised my answer, try outputting checkboxes individually and passing 'style' attribute in the options. That should create a style on the div that wraps around the label and input elements. If you need further control, use FormHelper to echo a label for each specific checkbox.